# Random string generator PHP

Tags: php, random

I'm trying to create a random string with numbers and letters and I found this function and thought it would be good, but I don't know if it is the correct way to create a true random string or if there is an easier way to do this? Below is what I have:

```
function randomGen() {
    $chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $length = strlen($chars);
    $random;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $random = $chars[rand(0, $length - 1)];
    }

    return $random;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with the function ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong as far as syntax. I just am not sure if this is the best way. Seeing some of the other answers I can tell that I'm using more code than necessary.

Comment: use str_shuffle instead of writing separate function.

Comment: You should have a look on this project : https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

Comment: Sorry string random must be of laravel itself

Comment: @myPClovesME S'pose it depends on what you want to use the random string for.

Comment: you could tack on `uniqid()` to that which would make it unique if uniqueness is what you're looking for. a lot of ways to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using `$random = substr(str_shuffle(MD5(microtime())), 0, 8);`, which will output the same amount of random characters as you have in your example. I actually prefer this method over most as it doesn't require you to put in the expected characters and even more importantly, it can be done in one line of code!